# Compare 2 observable collections and add to a third?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, observablecollection

I have two observable collections, one is a `fullteam` the other is `matchdayteam`. Is it possible to compare them and add any different entries on  `fullteam`  to another observable collection?

Comment: See also [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current answer is close, but no cigar. I fully answered the question in the comments for the first answer, but thought I would put it here for more visibility:

```
var fullteam = new ObservableCollection<string> { "John", "Mike", "Steve" };
var matchdayteam = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Peter", "Mike", "Jacob" };
var combined = new ObservableCollection<string>(fullteam.Union(matchdayteam));

// combined = John, Mike, Steve, Peter, Jacob
```

Comment: Exactly what I neede, just to see if i can implement it in my code now !

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure i understand what you mean but i believe you could use a where statement like:

```
var x = (ObservableCollection<string>) fullteam.Where(i => !matchdayteam.Contains(i));
```

like so:

```
var fullteam = new ObservableCollection<string>();
var matchdayteam = new ObservableCollection<string>();

fullteam.Add("one");
fullteam.Add("two");
matchdayteam.Add("one");

var x = (ObservableCollection<string>) fullteam.Where(i => !matchdayteam.Contains(i));
```

This should give you x which contains only the things in fullteam that is not in matchdayteam

Comment: You need to create a new `ObservableCollection(string)`. You cannot cast an `IEnumerable(string)` to `ObservableCollection(string)`.

Comment: order of your algorithm is `n^2` which may not be desirable

Comment: Or `var x = (ObservableCollection<string>) fullteam.Union(matchdayteam);`

Comment: @StephenPorter ugh. Thats much nicer.

Comment: Also @Romoku is correct, you cannot directly cast to an ObservableCollection<T>, so you would have to do the following: `var x = new ObservableCollection<string>(fullteam.Union(matchdayteam));`